# Create 1 pagination outside wordpress homepage

Tags: php, wordpress

[Wordpress] My homepage is being written in a template called template-home.php

I have queried 1 product (woocommerce) list by 1 category. I want to display 1 pagination right below it, how do I do that?

Link file template-home.php: https://prnt.sc/1t71zil
Website: https://holavietnam.vn/

Query:

```
<?php

$args = new WP_Query(array(

    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'field' => 'term_id',
            'terms' => 152,
        )
    )
));

if ($args->have_posts()) :

    while ($args->have_posts()) : $args->the_post();

?>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 pad_des">
            <div class="item_product_s wow flipInX">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
                    <div class="name_product_s">
                        <h3>
                            <?php the_title() ?>
                        </h3>

                        <p class=" price">
                            <del aria-hidden="true">
                                <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
                                    <bdi><?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_regular_price', true); ?><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">₫</span></bdi>
                                </span>
                            </del>
                            <ins>
                                <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
                                    <bdi><?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_sale_price', true); ?><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">₫</span></bdi>
                                </span>
                            </ins>
                        </p>

                    </div>
                </a>

                <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
                    <div class="zoom_product_s">
                        <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>

        </div>
<?php

    endwhile;

    wp_reset_postdata();

    wp_reset_query();

endif;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, we should add a query variable, default WordPress support `paged`, but I'm not sure that your homepage allows it. Just try it and let me know if it's not working.

`$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;`

Then, you add `the_posts_pagination();` at the end of `while`.

I updated your code, and I've not tested it yet. Just try to add it to check the result.

```
<?php

$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;

$args = new WP_Query(array(

    'posts_per_page' => 10,  // your product items per page here
    'paged'          => $paged,
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'field' => 'term_id',
            'terms' => 152,
        )
    )
));

if ($args->have_posts()) :

    while ($args->have_posts()) : $args->the_post();

?>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 pad_des">
            <div class="item_product_s wow flipInX">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
                    <div class="name_product_s">
                        <h3>
                            <?php the_title() ?>
                        </h3>

                        <p class=" price">
                            <del aria-hidden="true">
                                <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
                                    <bdi><?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_regular_price', true); ?><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">₫</span></bdi>
                                </span>
                            </del>
                            <ins>
                                <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
                                    <bdi><?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_sale_price', true); ?><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">₫</span></bdi>
                                </span>
                            </ins>
                        </p>

                    </div>
                </a>

                <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
                    <div class="zoom_product_s">
                        <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>

        </div>
<?php

    endwhile;

    the_posts_pagination();

    wp_reset_postdata();

    wp_reset_query();

endif;

?>
```

Comment: I tried it and it doesn't show pagination